# Perl regexp used for path sanitization PHP

Tags: php, regex, perl

I use those lines of code to secure the baseURI and requestURI for my website. What exactly do those lines do? I know they replace things around / with just / in some way.

```
$baseURI    = preg_replace('&/+&', '/', rtrim($baseURI, '/')).'/';
$requestURI = preg_replace('&/+&', '/', rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')).'/';
$requestURI = preg_replace('&\?.*?$&', '', $requestURI);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of the first and second lines is to remove duplicate consecutive slashes and ensure that the string finish by a slash:

```
rtrim($baseURI, '/') # remove leading slashes
&/+&    # looks for one or more slashes anywhere in the string 
        # to replace them by an unique slash
```

Then the replacement result is concatened with a `/` on the right.

You can replace these lines by:

```
$baseURI    = preg_replace('~/+|[^/]\K$~', '/', $baseURI);
$requestURI = preg_replace('~/+|[^/]\K$~', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

(where `\K` removes the start of the match from the match result)

The last line remove all the content from the first question mark (include) to the end of the string:

```
\?  # literal ?
.*? # all character zero or more time with a lazy quantifier (that is totally useless)
$   # end of the string
```

You can replace this line by:

```
$requestURI = preg_replace('~\?.*$~', '', $requestURI);
```

or

```
$arr = explode('?', $requestURI);
$requestURI = $arr[0];
```

**Important note:** If I understand well the goal of all of this, the third line must be placed before the second, since it will remove all (including slashes) from the question mark. A better choice is to replace these two last lines by:

```
$requestURI = preg_replace('~/+|(?:\?.*|[^/]\K)$~', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Note2: regex patterns used here are very basic. Taking a look at a [simple tutorial](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php)  or [making some tests](http://regex101.com) isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks:) I still have a hard time understanding all the regexps completely but I think I can figure it out.